# Blank page running Angular 9 app on ios 13

Tags: iphone, angular, ios13

I have issues loading my Angular 9 app on iPhone, it loads in all desktop browsers and android devices, just got an blank page in iPhone. It raises an promiseReactionJob exception in the polyfills-es2015 file .. running the lasted iOS version (13.4.1). I see the in the index.html, the scripts are loaded as expected.

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.c741d58c5f0062b819ef.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" type="module">    </script>
<script src="runtime-es5.c741d58c5f0062b819ef.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.1e423cd55d051bbc2156.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.367a122fcc429806387a.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es2015.80003c523586b89abce8.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.80003c523586b89abce8.js" crossorigin="use-credentials" nomodule defer></script>
```

It is production build: ng build --prod

The error below:

[image]

Or, disabling the --prod

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more details on that error? Also, is that an AOT/prod build?

Comment: It is production build: ng build --prod

Comment: Do you get the same error if building for debug? Regardless that you may get more infos about that error while not having a --prod deploy

Comment: It complains about core.js, see updated info

Comment: Even if this is an old issue, can you give it a try? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17587

Comment: I found the problem, Safari doesn't implement addEventListener/RemoveEventListener, so I got an undefined when I tried to use addEventListener from MediaMatcher api. (@angular/cdk/layout). I added an iOS check in my code to call the proper method and UI is loading fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due Safari/iOS doesn't implement addEventListener/RemoveEventListener, so the app called an undefined method and raised the exception. My fix was to add an iOS check and call addListener and removeListener only on iOS as addEventListener/RemoveEventListener were not in fem2015/layout.js loaded by Safari on iOS (tried iOS >= 12).