# Cross site tracking settings suddenly loading blank page in angular app

Tags: angular, browser, xss

I have 3 private angular v13 apps hosted. I am redirecting users to these apps from external web pages. One of my apps suddenly loading blank page in safari and iOS. I checked tsconfig file as guided in [Blank page with Angular (v14) app in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820261). I can see a question [Is there a workaround for Safari iOS "Prevent Cross Site Tracking" option, when issuing cookies from API on different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972162) where it's clear that there is no work around. But only one of my app is not loading. That was working before. I think it is an app issue. Please help me by listing some checks I should do to trouble shoot the issue. Or there is no way other than make them load from the same domain? Let me know if any more info is required.